# Can the red/green color combination for an accepted answer (in the reputation tab) be changed?

Tags: support, status-completed, design

When someone accepts an answer, the total rep for that answer shows up in my profile (in the reputation tab) as a red box with green text inside. This is extremely hard to read and is a strain on the eyes. Can this color combination be changed to something more pleasant?

See screen shot:

[image]

Comment: This was a bug that affected all SE sites. It's been fixed a few days ago.

Comment: @JonH actually I spoke too soon. This was fixed for graduated SE sites, but not Beta(sketchy theme). The fix will go in tonight's production build.

Answer (score 4):

This is not specific to gardening -- gardening won't get its own theme until it is graduated from beta to a full-fledged Stack Exchange site.  All beta sites (well, except one, not sure what's up there) use this standard beta theme.  So, if you care about getting that addressed despite the fact that this is a temporary theme, you'll have to post your suggestion to http://meta.stackoverflow.com where issues that effect stack as a whole are handled.